# How to escape slash in url path in python?

Tags: python, url, python-2.6

I have a url like :- http://example.com/GetDetails/value/abc-1234

I'm using python urllib to fetch the url.

```
value = "abc-12345"
URL = "http://example.com/GetDetails/value/{0}"
response = urllib.urlopen(URL.format(urllib.quote_plus(value))).read()
```

This works fine. But if I have a slash in my value like - "XYZ/1234", it returns 400 Bad request.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: slash not back slash :)

Comment: When value is `XYZ/1234`, what would you _like_ URL to be? If the answer is "whatever makes the server not return a 400 Bad Request", then you need to determine what that would be.